# How to make buttons cover full screen width in Android Linear Layout?

Tags: android, layout, width, android-linearlayout

I have following three button in a Linear Layout with width `fill_parent`.

How can I set the width of these buttons to equally cover the whole screen area?

```
<Button 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:id="@+id/btnReplyMessage" 
   android:gravity="left"
   android:text="Reply" 
/>
    
<Button 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:id="@+id/btnMarkAsUnread"
   android:gravity="left" 
   android:text="Mark as unread" 
/>
            
<ImageButton 
   android:id="@+id/btnDeleteMessage"
   android:src="@drawable/imgsearch"
   android:gravity="right" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 />
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Give all buttons the following properties

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

`fill_parent` tells them to consume as much width as possible, and `weight` determines how that width shall be distributed, when more than one control are competing for the same space. (Try playing around with different values of `weight` for each button to see how that works)

Comment: it is only applicable for buttons or Edittext too??

Comment: pretty much everything you can place in a `LinearLayout` will have this behavior. you can play around with setting some values to `wrap_content` and some to `fill_parent`/`weight=1`. in that case the former will consume the space they need, and the latter divide the rest of the available space between them, according to their respective weight. if you set `orientation=vertical` at the parent `LinearLayout`, you can do the same thing with `height` instead.

Answer (score 7):

You should just specify these attributes for each button:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

So it should be something like that:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use following code:

```
  <Button
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

You must to do 0dp in width on every button.